# binding a key and programming input to anything.el

Tags: emacs, elisp

when i type C-u F9 I want anything.el to pop up a buffer of choices as if I had typed 
`M-x anything -shell*` manually.

In other words, I often invoke anything and look for all my shell buffers and so I would like to simplify this process.

Comment: FYI the current maintainer renamed anything.el to emacs-helm and [it has a quite responsive forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/emacs-helm).

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can define a simple function calling `anything` with a pre-filled `-shell*` input, and bind it to a key (for example <kbd>F9</kbd>):

```
(defun my/anything-shell ()
  (interactive)
  (anything :input "-shell*"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'my/anything-shell)
```

**2.** If your <kbd>F9</kbd> key is already bound to `usual-f9-command` and you want `anything-shell` to be called only when you specify a prefix argument (with <kbd>C-u F9</kbd>), then your key binding must be a bit more complex:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") (lambda (&optional arg)
                               (interactive "P")
                               (if arg
                                   (my/anything-shell)
                                 (usual-f9-command))))
```